# Verifying the method when $x^2+y^2=1$.

Tags: solution-verification

Before I show my method, I'll post an example question. (Also, this one is the start of my wonder.)

> $x^2+y^2=1, z^2+w^2=1$. Then, find the minimum and maximum of $xw+yz$.

Of course, It can be easily solved with the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Inequality, but I'll try to use my strategy.

\begin{align}
& \alpha=\arcsin(x), \beta=\arcsin(z). \\ 
& \therefore \arccos(y)=\alpha, \arccos(w)=\beta. \\ & xw+yz=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta). \\ 
& \therefore \min(xw+yz)=-1, \max(xw+yz)=1.
\end{align}

Like this, I found that if the variables satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$, we can use it as a trigonometric function. (Maybe a lot of people know about this.)

But, my question is:

> Is this method always valid when the variables $x, y$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=1$, and the question is asking about the minimum, maximum, or the range of quadratic polynomials?

If not, please let me know the counterexample of this.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. What does it mean to say that *the question is all about quadratic polynomials*? Can you formulate a logically precise version of your question?

Comment: If $x^2+y^2=1$, there exists $a$ such that $x=\cos a,y=\sin a$. This is true even if we allow $x,y,a\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: Further, if $x,y$ satisfy some quadratic equation that does not define a parabola, then there either exist constants $a,b,c,d,\theta$ such that $x=a\cos\theta+b,y=c\sin\theta+d$, or the same but with hyperbolic functions. Finding these constants is nontrivial, but they will exist.

Comment: Umm... just for the one who has downvoted this post, please tell me why you downvoted this post so that I can edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$\vert \langle (x,y),(w,z)\rangle\vert \leq \Vert (x,y)\Vert \cdot \Vert (w,z)\Vert$. Equivalently,
$$ \vert xw+yz\vert \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{w^2+z^2} =1$$

Comment: Yes, this is also a nice solution, but this was just an example to show my method. In fact, this has a lot of solutions. For example, $(x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2)=(xw+yz)^2+(xz-yw)^2$, so $(xw+yz)^2$ has a maximum of $1$, when $xz=yw$.